# sql query to get count of different classes attended

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a swim_attendance table

```
 student_name  date_attended cnt
 Bob             21-Aug-2013  1 
 Bob             10-Sep-2013  1
```

I have a karate_attendance table

```
 student_name  date_attended cnt
 Bob             20-Aug-2013  1
 Bob             21-Aug-2013  1
 Bob             21-Aug-2013  1
```

I am trying to get a count of swim attendance and karate attendance for each student

```
 student_name  swim_attendance  karate_attendance
 Bob               2              3
```

Comment: Don't have two tables.

Comment: have u tried something? I can post a query straight away, but would like to know your effort.

Comment: And why is there a `cnt` column?

Comment: ...plus, you have no PRIMARY KEY. This is a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it

```
select
student_name,
coalesce(sum(swim_attendance)) as swim_attendance,
coalesce(sum(karate_attendance)) as karate_attendance
from
(
  ( 
     select student_name,sum(cnt) as swim_attendance, 0 as karate_attendance
     from swim_attendance group by student_name
  )
  union all
  ( 
     select student_name,0 as swim_attendance, sum(cnt) as karate_attendance
     from karate_attendance group by student_name
  )
)x
group by student_name
;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9777/2)**

UPDATE : From the point raised by Straberry to sum() only once

```
select
student_name,
coalesce(sum(swim_attendance)) as swim_attendance,
coalesce(sum(karate_attendance)) as karate_attendance
from
(
  ( 
     select student_name,cnt as swim_attendance, 0 as karate_attendance
     from swim_attendance 
  )
  union all
  ( 
     select student_name,0 as swim_attendance, cnt as karate_attendance
     from karate_attendance 
  )
)x
group by student_name
;
```

Comment: I suspect that it would be more efficient to SUM only once

Comment: I see what you mean !!

Answer (score 1):

You can do so

```
select s.student_name ,
sum(cnt * coalesce(s.table_type = 'swim') ) swim_attendance,
sum(cnt * coalesce(s.table_type = 'karate') ) karate_attendance
from (
select student_name , 'swim' as table_type,cnt from swim_attendance 
union all
select student_name ,'karate' as table_type,cnt from karate_attendance
) s
group by s.student_name
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5cd7c/15)